# EzAPI Method not found

Tags: esapi, methodnotfound

My development environment

- Windows 10 2004 64 bit
- Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition Version 16.7.6
- SQL Server 2019
- [EzAPI2016](https://github.com/fpvmorais/EzApi2016)

Working with EzAPI to implement a sample workflow that read a table and write to another temp table in the same database. After create the OLEDB data source providing the corresponding data-flow context, when assign the connection-manager to the connection attribute of the previously crated source object, the error in the title happen.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Have a good day.

[image: See screen capture image for more details]

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

Found the solution removing the reference to Microsoft.SqlSever.DTSRuntimeWrap.dll (version 13) into the ezapi project, and updating it to version 15, in my environment under c:\windows\Microsoft.net folder.

Answer (score 0):

EzApi is just a wrapper of SQL Server libraries. SQL Server Integration Services have different versions based on SQL Server and therefore the dll libraries are different. You need to have proper dll versions and EzApi library in order to target spesific version of SQL Server for your package. In addition, there are different properties you can use and different Framework on ScriptTask.

```
SQLServer2008 https://github.com/koureasstavros/SQLServer2008EzApi https://www.nuget.org/packages/EzApi2008
SQLServer2012 https://github.com/koureasstavros/SQLServer2012EzApi https://www.nuget.org/packages/EzApi2012
SQLServer2014 https://github.com/koureasstavros/SQLServer2014EzApi https://www.nuget.org/packages/EzApi2014
SQLServer2016 https://github.com/koureasstavros/SQLServer2016EzApi https://www.nuget.org/packages/EzApi2016
SQLServer2017 https://github.com/koureasstavros/SQLServer2017EzApi https://www.nuget.org/packages/EzApi2017
SQLServer2019 https://github.com/koureasstavros/SQLServer2019EzApi https://www.nuget.org/packages/EzApi2019
SQLServer2022 https://github.com/koureasstavros/SQLServer2022EzApi https://www.nuget.org/packages/EzApi2022
```